# keyboard shortcut for Uppercase/Lowercase toggle in notepad?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notepad

Is there a `shortcut` for convert a uppercase string to lowercase and vice versa in `notepad`in `Windows 10`? (`Shift + f3` doesn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built-in to Notepad, no.

You may be able to implement such behavior using a third-party application, such as AutoHotKey, but Notepad itself is a very basic editor which does not include this (or pretty much any other) advanced functions.

Comment: Thanks @music2myear, Is there any default keyboard shortcut in windows 10. for example renaming folder name from lowercase to uppercase?

Comment: No, not that either.